# Is there implicit ListFragment margin/padding? How to remove it?

Tags: android, android-layout

While using `ListFragment` in my layout and I found out it has unwanted left margin - the red part on the image (which goes up to the action bar.

I haven't find any documentation on this issue, but hopefully someone will know - how can I remove this space?

You can see from the image that the margin is not on the list item level, but it is on some higher level - so I guess it's the fragment margin.

It is notable that other fragments are just fine and stretched to full screen width. The only problematic fragments are those who extends `ListFragment`.

[image: unwanted margin is in red]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I'm using ActionBarSherlock and was able to fix this with [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

First, I added this to my themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyle.MyApp</item>
    ...
</style>
```

This tells `SherlockListFragment` to use my custom style for its `ListView`. Then I added this custom style to my styles.xml:

```
<style name="ListViewStyle.MyApp" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    ...
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    ...
</style>
```

You could also try one of these settings:

```
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item> <!-- Instead of paddingLeft, if you want 0, everywhere -->
```

Pointing the ListView to my custom style fixed the problem for me. Essentially, setting the styles on the ListView Widget should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You are best overriding the layout as the padding is part of ListFragment default layout.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

so a layout similar to the following:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and then populate it in onCreateView()

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bet_statement_list, container, false);
...
}
```

A bit verbose, but is the most flexible way to do this.